# How to alter session to change date format via php - oracle SQL

Tags: php, sql

I am attempting to insert some dates to a database via PHP. The dates are in format DD-MM-YYYY.

Usualy when attempting to insert dates, I am given the error:

```
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
```

To fix this using oracle SQL developer, I execute the query:

```
"ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MM-YYYY'"
```

This then allows the dates to be inserted.

However, When trying to alter the dates/session via PHP:

```
    $dateStid = oci_parse($conn, "ALTER SESSION SET 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT' = 'DD-MM-YYYY';");
oci_execute($dateStid);
```

I am given the error message:

> ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

How can i insert dates of the format DD-MM-YYYY using PHP?

Comment: It may be possible to set the date format outside of PHP so that you don't need to execute the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` each time you need to perform an update. See: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=nls-date-format-200006

Comment: Are you sure you should have the single quotes around `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` in your PHP query?

Comment: Remove the trailing semicolon. Just `$dateStid = oci_parse($conn, "ALTER SESSION SET 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT' = 'DD-MM-YYYY'");`